# NotImplementedException but already call the method in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notimplementedexception

I would like to know, why did the NotImplementedException(); still appear even though I'm pretty sure that I have called the method?

this is the throw exception in my dsNBC.xsd designer:

```
internal int getLastIDbyMaxPeg()
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

and this is how I called the method in PegawaiControl.cs in a folder named Control :

```
public int getNumID()
{
     return Peg.getLastIDbyMaxPeg();
}

public string generateIDPeg()
{
    string id = "PEG";
    return id + Convert.ToString(getNumID() + 1);
}
```

and in the boundary layout I just called the generateIDPeg() into a local variable like this : `string idPegw = PC.generateIDPeg();`

Well, getLastIDbyMaxPeg() is a name of method in the query dataset of dsNBC.xsd that I created. So the actual implementation code for that method is the query in dataset. I got consufed here how can I implement the query as the actual implementation in the throw exception? 
[You can see the StackTrace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKrnw.png)

Can you help me?

Comment: If you call the method, and the only thing the method is doing is throwing an exception, then you'll get an exception...  You need to remove the `throw new System.NotImplementedException();` line and implement your own code there.

Comment: The line `throw new System.NotImplementedException();` is placeholder text. You need to return some int from that method.

Comment: Can you add a stack trace of the exception to your question?

Comment: Another one for the "why does it do what I tell it to, please make it stop" tag.

Comment: "Implemented" doesn't mean what you think it does. "Implementing" a method is when you edit the code to *delete* the `throw` statement, and then you replace it with your own code that does something useful.

Comment: but the code for getLastIDbyMaxPeg is query because it's a name for method from a DataSet. So what should I write? @EugenePawlik

Comment: is this real life?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove that code and replace it with your actual implementation.
The method has not been implemented (i.e. made to actually *do* something, rather than throwing the `NotImplementedException`), only called.

It will not just automatically remove itself because you *call* the method, you must supply the implementation.

Place your logic inside of the method and remove the current line to fix your situation:

```
internal int getLastIDbyMaxPeg()
{
    //Do some things
    //return some int value
}
```

Comment: but the getLastIDbyMaxPeg() is a name of method that I create in a DataSet to find the last max id from the database so the code is the query... That's why there is a "Peg." in front of getLastIDbyMaxPeg() because Peg is the variable for the tableAdapter... how can I placed the code into the internal int getLastIDbyMaxPeg while the code itself is a query for dataset? @DangerZone

Comment: That's a different question entirely. You will need to research how to do queries in C# and place your query in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You have, indeed, called the getLastIDbyMaxPeg() method, which is the source of your problem.

This exception means exactly what it says: you didn't implement the getLastIDbyMaxPeg() method before you called it. Right now all getLastIDbyMaxPeg does is throw a `NotImplementedException()`. (That exception is a standard "placeholder" for a method that needs to be implemented but hasn't been yet).

If you replace `throw new NotImplementedException()` with an actual implementation your problem will be fixed.